# How to visualize the water equivalent between two raster layers in arcmap 10.1?

Tags: arcmap, raster

I do have two raster layers (interpolated with Empirical Bayesian Kriging), that show the elevation of a glacier in April, and September. I want to show the change in elevation between the layers in water equivalent. Any suggestion on how I can do that?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what you mean by "water equivalent".  If you're just wanting to find the difference between the two rasters, it's a simple matter of subtracting the two in [Raster Calculator](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000z7000000.htm).

Your expression will look something like this:

```
"September" - "April"
```

or

```
Abs("September" - "April")
```

You will need the Spatial Analyst extension.